# How can I get the path of a module dynamically?

Tags: perl, module

If I have something like this:

In some script.pl:

```
#code here  
my $result = $class->foo();  
# extra code here
```

In the module of the class:

```
package Test::A::Foo;  
use parent Test::A;  

sub foo {  
 # code here  
}
```

How can I get the exact file path where `Test::A::Foo` resides when I am executing code inside the module? It is not the working directory as I am running the `script.pl` and that calls the `$class->foo`, so how can I get the actual path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The built-in hash `%INC` contains the resolved paths to module files that have been loaded using `require` or `do`

The location of the `pm` file for `Test::A::Foo` is in `$INC{'Test/A/Foo.pm'}`

Something like

```
$INC{ (__PACKAGE__ =~ s|::|/|gr) . '.pm' }
```

should do what you need

Comment: But how do I get `Test::A::Foo`? Via `__PACKAGE__` and replacing `::` with `/`? Because I would like to make it for any module